# When is it a good time to give up on a bad question?

Tags: support, closing-questions

I tried to ask a [Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48894/normal-distributed-random-numbers-in-time-expected-behaviour-askew-distribut), about 6 days ago.
Since I am new to the field, apparently my question apparently is too broad or vague. I have read a [good guide, how to ask good questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated), but sadly this does not help me enough. My question is that vague because of my lack of experience.
For future questions I will read [a book on thermal and statistical physics.](http://stp.clarku.edu/notes/) But what about this question? **How long should I hold on to my question before deleting it?**
I could simply leave it, hoping someone will understand and answer it one day, but apparently it is not a good question. Therefore I do not want it to mess up this beautiful site.
When is it a good time to give up on a bad question?

Comment: It would be better for you to edit. Have you tried [looking in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) to see if anyone could help you improve your question?

Comment: Don't delete your answer, and don't necessarily give up at that point. It looks like you already received some feedback on your question, which suggests that it probably has some interest.

Comment: I have an answer half-written.  The problem in completing it is that your question is indeed vague, so I have to spend a lot of time making and explaining assumptions.

Comment: Thank you all just so much! I currently am in the suggested chat room, where I could hopefully answer questions to what I want - in layman's terms.

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old thread, I think this subject fits well in the context of the new rules of putting questions on hold, so they can be edited, before closed.

I think the answer is: NEVER!!

You showed that it is possible to revert a situation (your question has now 6 upvotes and a good answer).

Other users helped you with that, but just because you came on Meta and shared your difficulties.

Besides Meta, you used other strategies such as: awarding a bounty and being available in chat to clarify possible doubts about the question.

This thread is an example to current/future users that improving the quality of a question is always possible.