# The editing of "thanks very much" at end of posts

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette, signatures

Whenever I make a post on a stack exchange account, over any of my accounts, I will almost always write "thanks very much for any help" at the end. This frequently gets edited out, I was wondering why? For examples, see here:

[Box-Jenkins Forecasting With ARIMA(p,d,q) models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149635/box-jenkins-forecasting-with-arimap-d-q-models)

[Showing a Time Series is Regular](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149615/showing-a-time-series-is-regular)

[Combining Force of Mortality for F and M to find $l_x$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147298/combining-force-of-mortality-for-f-and-m-to-find-l-x)

I have omitted my customary "thanks very much for any help" here, it may be noted.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/whats-the-site-policy-on-removing-text-such-as-thankyou-or-this-question-is/1996). (I wouldn't have bothered in this case if I wasn't already editing your q.)

Comment: @Scortchi Ok, thanks. I asked as on math.stackexchange, where the majority of my post are located, my "thank you" statements are normally left in but here it seemed they were being rapidly removed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Did you thank me twice in the comment to make up for the lack of thanks in the question? ;)

Comment: Just for the record, I also had the habit to write 'thanks' in all asked questions. But got convinced not to [some time ago](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/tags-on-meta-cv-about-questions).

Comment: @Scortchi I didn't even notice I had done that!

Comment: @AndreSilva Yeah I have never really been convinced about the arguments against thanking people. I can see why similar things such as "this is too easy" or "I'm not a mathematician/statistician.." should be omitted but I see distinct differences between the two. First the second kind of statements often appear in titles or at the start of questions and so are read by anyone who wants to view the question and can be a distraction, unlike thanks which appears at the end and doesn't, in my opinion disrupt the clarity of a question.

Comment: The second is that I don't think they add any value at all where as I feel that saying thanks is a genuine signal of appreciation.

Comment: I will of course defer to the practices of the specific forum that I am posting in and will endeavor to refrain thanking people at the end of posts.

Comment: You can always leave a comment to thank for a good answer that your question received. This is often done here and perfectly tolerated (especially if the comment is a bit more substantial than just "thank you"). So essentially you may (and perhaps should even try to) say thank you, but *after* you got an answer, not *before*. And in the comments space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why "thanks" and other salutations are edited is to remove noise from questions/answers, so readers can know what posts are about more easily.

The following posts have complementary information:

[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) (main Meta SE site).

[What's the site policy on removing text such as "thank you", or "This question is too easy"](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/whats-the-site-policy-on-removing-text-such-as-thankyou-or-this-question-is/1996) (CV meta).