# Is it ok to ask for guidance on my research project?

Tags: support, questions

I am a novice in statistics and would like some guidance in data analysis for my research project.  I just want to make sure that it is ok to post my research question, method, and ask the community for guidance to obtain results?

Comment: That's what the forum is for. But look at the Help Center to get guidance on what to post, and what not to, and look at some past questions, especially for questions that look like yours and got upvoted answers. What helps is being specific, explaining your question precisely and concisely and having a new question. Questions of the form "I am working on X and wondering how to analyse my data" have less chance of a good reply.

Comment: @NickCox, why not make that an official answer?

Comment: @gung OK; thanks for encouragement.

Answer (score 7):

That's what the forum is for.

But look at the Help Center to get guidance on what to post, and what not to, and look at some past questions, especially for questions that look like yours and got upvoted answers.

Helpful general pages include

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

There is also much good advice within this thread here:

[How to ask a “good” question on CrossValidated?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated)

What helps is being specific, explaining your question precisely and concisely, and having a new question.

Questions of the form "I am working on X and wondering how to analyse my data" have less chance of a good reply.