# Aside from a bounty how can I give incentive to users to answer my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, unanswered-questions, participation

Aside from a bounty how can I give incentive to users to answer my question?
I know there is this new bounty feature, but I was wondering if there are other ways too.

Comment: The most important thing is making your question clear & interesting to as many users as you can. Pay especial attention to the title & to selecting a variety of relevant tags.

Comment: Do you mean "answer" rather than "ask"? (Also the bounty feature really isn't new). Getting the question as clear and engaging as possible is much more important than a bounty.

Comment: @Glen_b yes I meant answer, sorry, I've just edited the question. I noticed the bounty only recently and was wondering if there are any other similar tools to help "promoting" a question.

Comment: About the advices provided by our moderators, this post can help: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated

Comment: To the other suggestions I would add--after reviewing some of your highly voted questions and others with no votes--that you should attempt to ask your question *as briefly as possible.*  I suspect that any time a question exceeds one page, it will lose a majority of potential readers unless it is so engagingly asked and illustrated that people really enjoy reading through it.  Even if you feel that offering many details is necessary, *ask your question at the outset* so that people know what it's about, whether they are interested in it, and whether they might be able to answer.

Comment: @whuber makes a very good point there. Take your recent question [Simulating the game of bingo using a Monte Carlo approach. Is this methodology correct?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/174500/17230) as an example. I only read to the bottom of that because I wanted to give you tips on asking questions owing to this Meta post. If it had started along the lines of "I simulated 500 bingo games in which each of 150 contestants should have had an equal chance of winning, & was surprised to find the proportion of games won by each [...]" I think it'd've been answered more quickly.

Comment: Some other things: (1) More people (though still not many) will read through code if it's well commented, perhaps showing examples of outputs at particular steps. (2) An accumulation of very minor hindrances to ease of reading (such as irrelevancy, poor formatting of equations, typos, & mislabelled or unlabelled plots) can put people off IMO.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I'll try to improve the way I ask questions. I sometimes feel that giving as much details as possible helps but clearly it's not always the case.

Comment: Writing an engaging question is not easy. Many of my questions didn't do well for this reason.

Comment: @Glen_b I know, sometimes I'm so deep in a topic that I make a mess when trying to ask a question.. But I must say, in general in my experience people here on Cross Validated are really nice and polite and try to help even though the question isn't perfect.

Comment: @AndreSilva: with regard to your title edit, see http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Incentivize. I am not a native English speaker so my personal opinion is of little importance, but the word does sound pretty awful to me.

Comment: I rolled the edit back (@amoeba)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Scortchi said:

> The most important thing is making your question clear & interesting to as many users as you can. Pay especial attention to the title & to selecting a variety of relevant tags.

We have a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post specifically written to help users asking clear and  good questions:

[How to ask a "good" question on CrossValidated?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated)

@whuber still provides further guidance:

> ...one should attempt to ask a question as briefly as possible. I suspect that any time a question exceeds one page, it will lose a majority of potential readers unless it is so engagingly asked and illustrated that people really enjoy reading through it. Even if one feel that offering many details is necessary, ask a question at the outset so that people know what it's about, whether they are interested in it, and whether they might be able to answer.

Another reference to read (from the main Meta Stack Exchange) is: [How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/how-can-i-get-answers-fast), which is in accordance to what was already said here. An extra point I'd like to emphasize from there is:

> - Keep refining/editing your questions until they are perfect.

specially if someone leaves a comment asking for clarifications; respond to it as fast as you can (i.e., not only respond in the comments, but edit the question to clarify it too).