# Is asking for help finding relevant research off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have trouble finding relevant research in a specific sub-field. Is it off topic for Cross Validated to either ask for such research or ask for help in finding it? How could I make it a better fit for the site instead of just a lazy cry for help?

The field itself is relevant to Cross Validated. I would be asking about time series literature, specifically related to the behavior of time series features when it comes to shortening or lengthening the series.

Comment: Is the subfield statistics or machine learning?  It isn't obvious to me that this would be off topic.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I think it's more a question of whether asking for research is off topic. But the field could be both statistics or machine learning. I'm sure you're aware that they are closely related, and in this case it doesn't make a difference to me. They both have an extensive front in time series analysis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reference request are (often) on-topic, but try to make it as concrete and specific as possible, maybe with an (applied?) example? Maybe you could include a (simulated?) data example.

Have a look through [this list of posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breferences%5D+resear*+closed%3Ano+-book+-textbook) and the specific example [What is the current research on missing not at random data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95376/what-is-the-current-research-on-missing-not-at-random-data)

There is good advice about asking questions in [How to ask a "good" question on CrossValidated?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated)

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that I like to do, to help those helping me, is to show that I have done a credible effort.  I show where I have looked, and I update it as I progress.

The goal here is teaching and sometimes finding.  Communicating knowledge.  The form isn't always "I know x" but is often and commendably "This person at *reference* did y".

In my personal opinion, this is more of a "how do you go about asking the question" and the "may I ask this type of question" is already answered in the affirmative.