# Feedback on question: E-commerce - Does higher delivery time lead to lower sales?

Tags: discussion

I've recently asked a question [E-commerce - Does higher delivery time lead to lower sales?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/627135/e-commerce-does-higher-delivery-time-lead-to-lower-sales). In this question I ask for help on finding appropriate statistical methods on a problem that I am facing. My question was closed as off-topic.

Can I get feedback on my question? What is the question missing to be welcomed by the community?

I've read the answers on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a "good" question on CrossValidated?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated). It seems to me that my question is on topic (applied statistical analysis), short, specific, clear, and concise. I intentionally left out the description of data and programming language, as I believe it would not serve the question to make it specific in that way. What did I miss?

Comment: +1 for doing some research & coming here to seek more information.  That's refreshing from someone whose Q was closed.

Comment: I just read your Q.  Others will be able to answer better, since they were involved, but I would say you will need to provide more information.  There are lots of ways, potentially, to try to find out what you want to know.  Which is right / best is impossible to know without more information.  It looked like there are some comments on the Q asking for more information.  I would advise that you engage with them to provide what they need.

Comment: Also related are these answers https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5315/ and https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4467/  to "Top k List of Reasons to Close a Question Immediately"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was one of the reviewers who vtc your question. But AFAIR, I thought the post was unclear and didn't provide enough information and material that could garner a quality based informative and concise answer.

Namely, there you wrote your product delivery time varies throughout the time. But how? (I see the same has been raised as a comment by [dimitriy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/627135/e-commerce-does-higher-delivery-time-lead-to-lower-sales#comment1169828_627135)). You said you want your test based on historical data. Well then at least provide a snippet of it! What does it contain? What's the format? Etc.

Then you asked for an example to show the purported test based on a toy historical data.

Overall, albeit the post could have to some extent a statistical query, the dearth of some useful information renders it unanswerable, imo. Of course, I think it can be salvaged provided you are able to reply to the response sought and supply some critical information necessary for an answerable query. That was my take of your post.

If others think differently, they can surely vote to reopen.

Comment: +1, this is a helpful and respectful answer.

Comment: Thank you. In an attempt to make the question short, I made it unclear. I've rewritten the question now, clarifying the points you and @dimitriy mention

Comment: Looking in a way better format @Draex_. Have voted to reopen and it is reopened now.